# Difference between using super.key and (Key? key) : super(key: key) in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to know what's the difference between using {super.key} and (Key? key) : super(key: key) in a flutter app.
I mean I know they both set key from the super widgets, but why there is 2 types of them? and which is preferred to use?

```
class MyPublicWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  MyPublicWidget({super.key});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `super.key` is just syntactic sugar for the other form, makes the code shorter and easier to read. It was introduced in Dart 2.17. You should definitely use it!

Comment: and there is a lint rule `use_super_parameters` that you can enable to get a warning and quick fix in the IDE.

https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules/use_super_parameters